# is it possible to make an 100% browser based javascript twitter client (no back end at all) using oAuth?

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth

is it possible to make an 100% browser based javascript  twitter client (no back end at all) using oAuth?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. You still need a secure way to get an access key from twitter and you may want to hide your consumer secret key.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [I suppose.](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/)

Related: [JavaScript OAuth sign in with Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470694/javascript-oauth-sign-in-with-twitter)

Comment: See first link that was provided by quantumSoup - Unauthenticated access has been suspended. It is not possible to do a browser only solution unless you're comfortable storing authentication data publicly for everybody to see.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is possible** to implement a Secure 100% browser based javascript twitter client using oAuth.

You can do this by using YQL & YUI.

There is a open-source project called ***Tweetanium*** that shows how to implement that in ***JavaScript***.

References:

- https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing
- https://github.com/derek/Tweetanium
- http://www.tweetanium.net