# Javascript function - FB oAuth function turn it for the twitter oAuth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refactoring, twitter-oauth

I'm actually using this js function for the facebook connect.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
   FB.init({ 
    appId: '371***********',
     status: true,
      cookie: true,
       xfbml: true ,
       oauth:true,
       channelUrl: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>fb-channel-file.php' //this domain
     });
};
(function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script');
   e.type = 'text/javascript';
   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
   e.async = true;
   document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e);
}());
// FB LOGIN -->

function FBlogin(){
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(r){
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if(response.authResponse) {
        $.ajax({
          type:'GET',
          url: _config_base_url+'/auth/ajax_login',
          dataType:'json',
          data:{'fb_at':response.authResponse.accessToken},
          beforeSend:function(){
            notify('Loading ...',false,'notify-info');
          },
          error:function(_response){
              notify('An error occurred, please try again later.',false); 

            },
            success:function(json){
              notify_destroy();

              window.location.href= _config_base_url+'/profile';

            }
          });
      } else {}
    },{scope:'email'/*,user_birthday,user_location*/});
  });
}
```

Now i would like to reproduce the same/quite the same, function for allowing people to connect via `Twitter`, i just turned that for `Google+`,
 but i really can't understand how to turn it up for the `Twitter oAuth.`

Any idea?

Comment: Your pastebin link is dead.

Comment: i'll update anyway the code is this one i posted

Answer (score 3):

### Update

- [Here's an up-voted answer with an explicit example and a comment discussion on security.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1286921/1085891) From: [application that uses OAuth and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221371/application-that-uses-oauth-and-javascript)
- Possibly helpful tutorials

  - [How-to: Secure OAuth in JavaScript](http://derek.io/blog/2010/how-to-secure-oauth-in-javascript/)
  - [How to Authenticate Users With Twitter OAuth](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/)

### Original Answer

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5003176/1085891) to [JavaScript OAuth sign in with Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470694/javascript-oauth-sign-in-with-twitter) reads like it's not possible or not the best approach to take due to security.

  > Problem with this is that anyone who views your page can also now view
  >   your consumer key and secret which must be kept private.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > Twitter do state that every possible effort **must** be made to keep these
  >   values private to avoid this happening
  >
  > Unfortunately, there is currently no way to use oAuth in Browser based
  >   JavaScript securely.
- [jsOAuth](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth) might be helpful but, as mentioned in the above answer, security is an issue.

  > jsOAuth is a javascript library implementing the OAuth protocol.
  >   jsOAuth aims to form the basis of custom clients such as Twitter and
  >   Yahoo.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > **For security reasons jsOAuth doesn't run in the browser. Browsers are only mentioned here for running the test suite.**

Comment: Twitter Javascript OAuth going to deprecated soon. Better aware of that.